# Visual Studio 2022 source file locations, how to set?

Tags: c++, debugging

Windows 11, 64-bit, Visual Studio 2022 (17.4.5), C++ and Intel Fortran

I keep my project's source files and executables in a set of directories ("WORKING").
When I release an update of my app, I save the executable, .pdb and all source files in a separate set of directories ("PRIOR").

When I want to debug a prior version of the app, I locate the .exe of the prior app, double-click in File Explorer, open VS2022, and attach to the app's process. Then I open a source file in the PRIOR tree ("SOURCE") and set a breakpoint. When the app reaches the breakpoint, it loads the source file with the same name (i e, SOURCE) from WORKING, not PRIOR. Since these two source files are usually different, this makes it very difficult to debug, since I am seeing incorrect source lines as I step thru the pgm.

Opening the VS debug window Modules shows that my process is using the .pdb from PRIOR, as it should be, but the source files are coming from WORKING. I have not found any way to tell VS  where to look  for the source files.

How can I get VS to use the source files in the PRIOR tree when debugging the PRIOR .exe/.pdb?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-source-files-common-properties-solution-property-pages-dialog-box?view=vs-2022

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this reference. I have tried it, and it does not work as advertised. As soon as I set a breakpoint in the file I have loaded from PRIOR, it locates and opens the same file in WORKING, and shows the breakpoint at the same line #. In the Solution Properties window, I have added PRIOR o the list of directories to look in, and WORKING to the list of directories to avoid. Any suggestions?

Comment: On further testing, I've found that Properties/Debug source files works properly for C++ source, but not for Fortran, so it's probably an Intel Fortran problem, not Visual Studio.